# Didn't open popup window - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create popup window using bootstrap and when I click the open login window button the popup window didn't show up. I did this watching tutorial and did the same as it shows. I can't find the error here. Can someone help me with this? Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>images</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h3>Login Demo</h3>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">open login window</button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <!--header-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h2 class="modal-title">Login</h2>
                    </div>

                    <!--body (content)-->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <!--footer (button)-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to include jQuery before Bootstrap JS file.

Comment: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: thanks :) It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add jQuery for bootstrap script to work correctly.
The simplest way is to add a script tag similar to:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

just before bootstrap script:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```